# array name and pointer name confusion

Tags: c

In C language, an Array is a collection of same data type, that is when we are defining an array like this :

```
int my_list[50];
```

we are allocating 50 consecutive location in the computer memory to store 50 integer.

when somebody says my array is "my_list", what does it mean? does it collectively denotes all the 50 spaces that I have defined in the memory?

if that is the case , when I'm trying to learn pointers, they say, no no, there is a pointer whose name is "my_list" and it points to my_list[0];

my conclusions are like this:
"my_list" **does** denote all the 50 memory location collectively, but when we are defining the array , the machine is generating a pointer whose name is "accidentally" "my_list" and it points to my_list[0];

array my_list denotes all the 50 location collectively and pointer my_list only points to my_list[0], though their name overlaps they are totally different things.

please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does it collectively denotes all the 50 spaces that I have defined in the memory?

Yes, `my_list` is the array.

> … they say, no no, there is a pointer whose name is "my_list" and it points to my_list[0];

“They” are wrong. There is no pointer named `my_list`.

However, when an array is used in an expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, is the operand of unary `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Thus, if you, for example, use `my_list` like a pointer, as in `int *p = my_list + 5;`, or you pass it to a function, as in `foo(50, my_list);`, then it is automatically converted to a pointer, as if you had written `int *p = &my_list[0] + 5;` or `foo(50, &my_list[0]);`.

For the exceptions: With `sizeof`, `sizeof my_list` gives the size of the whole array, the size of 50 `int`. There is no automatic conversion to a pointer, so `sizeof my_list` does not give the size of a pointer. And with unary `&`, `&my_list` is a pointer with type “pointer to array of 50 `int`” rather than a pointer with type “pointer to pointer to `int`”.

(An array you declare with a name, like `my_list`, is of course not a string literal. A string literal can be used to initialize an array, as in `char MyString[] = "Hello";`. In this case, the array formed by the string literal is used to initialize `buffer`; it is not converted to a pointer.)